# How do I write a Firebase timestamp and write it again to another location

Tags: firebase

I am using Firebase.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP at one location within the firebase.
After I write it, I would like to also store that same value at another location.

Is there a shortcut to do this? For example, a way to return the timestamp value that was written?  Do I have to read the location of the timestamp back out using .once()?

Thanks in advance,

Aaron

Answer (score 1):

A once() would work okay:

```
var fb = new Firebase(URL);
fb.set( Firebase.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP, function(err) {
   if( !err ) {
      fb.once('value', function(snap) {
         console.log('the timestamp', snap.val());
      });
   }
});
```

You could also utilize a transaction, which passes a snapshot to the success method:

```
var fb = new Firebase(URL);
fb.transaction(function() {
   return Firebase.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP;
}, function(err, success, snap) {
   if( err ) { console.error(err); }
   else { console.log('the timestamp', snap.val()); }
});
```